# Upon runnning a script, I always get "undefined" as a result

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I've been trying to scrape next page link iteratively from a webpage using `axios` and `cheerio`. When I run the script, I always get `undefined` as a result. How can I get next page link until there is no more?

This is my current attempt:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const base = "https://stackoverflow.com";
const url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping";

async function main(){
  const data = await axios.get(url,{
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
    }
  });
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  let nextPage = $('a[rel="next"]').eq(0).attr("href");
  console.log(nextPage);
  
  while(nextPage){
    url = base + nextPage;
    const data = await axios.get(url,{
      headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
      }
    });
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    nextPage = $('a[rel="next"]').eq(0).attr("href");
    console.log(nextPage);
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolved promise from `axios.get` is a response object which contains the actual html-response body under `<axiosResponse>.data`. So if you change it to the following, it should work:

```
...
const response = await axios.get(url,{
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
    }
  });
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
...
```